# How to display the standard progress dialog when copying files?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream, progressdialog, shell32

Windows has a nice dialog when copying files, which shows the progress. I want to re-use this dialog when I copy files from C#. I probably need some P/Invoke calls for this, can someone show me how to do it?

I'm aware that in the `VisualBasic` namespace, the `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory` function provides a dialog too that I could use from C#, but that dialog is slightly different than the real one.

Comment: You want to use exact the same dialog while copying the files? cz You can use the `ProgressBar` and `BackgroundWorker` to do the same thing.

Comment: There's a ProgressBar that gets values from 1 to 100. you need to use that with a timer/threads to make it look live. I donno the copy API, but if you can get current copy progress than you can set the ProgressBar accordingly.

Comment: [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx) and/or [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb775771(v=vs.85).aspx) would be the way to ask the windows shell to perform copy operations - which would then take care of showing dialogs (unless you suppress them), but it's going to be a world of fun COM interop to make it happen.

Comment: @AlexJolig I know I could use a progressbar, but the Win8 dialog is very advanced (charts, time estimation). I don't want to re-implement all that logic.

Comment: I found this article: [C# does Shell](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3590/C-does-Shell-Part), which included a wrapper library around `SHFileOperation`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I already was looking at SHFileOperation and found this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3590/C-does-Shell-Part , so this question is solved it seems.